# How to send an image file through XHR request to fastAPI

Tags: javascript, python, image, xmlhttprequest, fastapi

Dont know how to send image through request as base64 string to store it as blob object in sqlite FastAPI framework and has no idea about which method to use, using formdata or ???
is there any method to do above mentioned task

```
var pimagefile  = document.getElementById("pImage").files[0];
var pimageblob  = new Blob([pimagefile],{type: 'image/jpg'});

function convertToBase64(){
       var pimageBase64 = // convert to base64 string
}
var toSend = {
        pimage: pimageBase64
}


var jsonString = JSON.stringify(toSend);

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/add/", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhttp.send(jsonString);
```

Comment: See this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804) as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData().

```
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append("filename.txt",blob);
xhr.open("POST","url",true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

Comment: By using this method can I send other text info's gathered by input fields in submit form ?.....

Comment: I think yes you can. For example you have an Form with text inputfields and file upload. with formdata you can collect all data and pass to the request.