# FastAPI POST Request Handling for FormData Based File Upload - Error 422/400

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, post, fastapi

I am currently prototyping some code that takes two form data inputs one being a title for the file being uploaded, and the other the file itself however I keep running into Error 422 or Error 400 depending on the changes I have made to the code. FastAPI is a new library to me so I am not particularly well versed in the syntax. My code sections are as follows:

FastAPI Handle

```
@app.post("/create_taskboard/")
async def create_taskboard(request: Request, taskboard_name: str, spreadsheet: UploadFile):
    try:
        # Store the uploaded spreadsheet in the 'spreadsheets' folder
        spreadsheet_path = f"spreadsheets/{spreadsheet.filename}"
        with open(spreadsheet_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(spreadsheet.file.read())

        # Create a new Taskboard instance and stage the spreadsheet
        taskboard = Taskboard(
            taskboard_name, len(taskboards) + 1, 5, 5, "taskboard_db.sqlite"
        )
        taskboard.stage(spreadsheet_path)
        taskboard.commit()

        # Add the Taskboard instance to the dictionary
        taskboards[taskboard_name] = taskboard

        return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Taskboard created successfully"})
    except Exception as e:
        return JSONResponse(content={"error": str(e)}, status_code=500)
```

Javascript

```
    // Handle form submission to create a new Taskboard
    $("#createTaskboardForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var taskboardName = $("#taskboardName").val();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("taskboard_name", taskboardName);
        formData.append("spreadsheet", $("#spreadsheetFile")[0].files[0]);
        

        // Send a POST request to create a new Taskboard
        console.log("Sending POST request...");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/create_taskboard/",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("POST request successful:", response);
                alert(response.message);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error("POST request failed:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                alert("Error creating Taskboard.");
            }
        });
    });
```

I also want to note that I am using CORS with FastAPI but removing this didn't seem to help.

```
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],  # Change this to a specific origin in production
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

When contentType is set to 'false' in the JS I get error 422 Unprocessesable Entity and when it is set to 'multipart/form-data' I get error '400 Bad Request'

Adding this statement into the JS before the AJAX statement:

```
for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Returns:

```
taskboard_name, t
main.js:40 spreadsheet, [object File]
```

Which as far as I can tell is correct. Debugging the Python has proved ineffective, as when I put a "raise TypeError" statement as the first line after the handle is created it never raises. This leads me to beleive that the JS is at fault, however I have been led to beleive that everything else is pointing at the backend code. After two hours on this same issue I am at a loss, any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to use FastAPI's Form, instead of request https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804)