# Uploading Files From React Native To Fast Api

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, fastapi

```
import apiClient from "./client";

interface PostFormValues {
  title: string;
  recipeSteps: string[];
  images: string[];
}

const postRecipe = async (data: PostFormValues) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("title", data.title);
  data.recipeSteps.forEach((step, index) => {
    formData.append(`steps`, step);
  });

  data.images.forEach((image, index) => {
    fetch(image.uri)
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        // Create a new file object from the blob
        const file = new File([blob], "filename");

        // Append the file to the FormData object
        formData.append("images", file);

        // Now you can proceed to send this FormData object with the file data to your server
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching file:", error));
  });

  const endpoint = "/post_ingredients/";
  return apiClient.post(endpoint, formData, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  });
};

export { postRecipe };
```

---

```
@app.post("/post_ingredients/")
async def post_ingredients(title: str = Form(), steps: list[str] = Form(), images: list[UploadFile] = File(),  db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    return None
```

---

{"images": [{"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CE2DB7DE-F5A2-46D7-8AE7-4971BB04F106/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/@anonymous/RecipeApp-cc37927b-23e7-4a13-aeb7-ea9c033425cf/ImagePicker/E26410FB-C7DA-4B87-B3B3-98A92FE59573.png"}, {"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/CE2DB7DE-F5A2-46D7-8AE7-4971BB04F106/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/@anonymous/RecipeApp-cc37927b-23e7-4a13-aeb7-ea9c033425cf/ImagePicker/2CBDA9CA-C671-4D52-85D1-927C788B5B3B.jpg"}], "recipeSteps": ["D"], "title": "F"}

Image is not uploading and I keep getting 422 error with an message of loc : [Array], msg: "field required".

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74810115/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804) helpful as well.